# Packaging Einstein/Tableau artifacts in 2GP Managed Extension fails

Tags: managed-package, einstein-analytics, platform-bug, 2gp, tableau-crm

I'm currently working on a 2GP Managed Package that bundles Einstein Analytics (a.k.a. Tableau CRM) artifacts like `templates`, `dashboards`, `datasets`, `dataflows`.

When I upload a new version using SFDX commands I run into this error:

> No Dataset found for Developer Name: Dataset_Name

It looks like this already fixed Platform Bug https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A000000mDIhQAM&title=analytics-unable-to-save-dashboard-when-using-dataset-created-via-managed-package is coming back in 2GP.

**Important:** My 2GP is an extension package to a **1GP** Managed Package. The dependency is stated in my `sfdx-project.json`.